# Can we convert string to html in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Can I convert a string to HTML in javascript?

```
let description = "<a className="peoplelink" id="ether">Ether</a> // is render as 'the historian of the'";

     let html= // I know that it is easy to do with jquery by using .html() method, but can we convert a string to HTML in javascript?
```

Comment: What's the goal ? What have you tried

Comment: Use single quotes instead of double quotes to wrap around the string, `let foo = '<img src="..." />';`

Comment: better to use backtick

Comment: @Weedoze I want to convert string to html like this : ``<a className="peoplelink" id="ether">Ether</a> is the historian of the <a className="peoplelink" id="jaredites">Jaredites</a>.`` I am react js developer and I want to change string to html without  used jquery.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing to convert, is a simple string to innerHtml:

I.E.:

```
const markup = `
 <div class="person">
    <h2>
        ${person.name}
    </h2>
    <p class="location">${person.location}</p>
    <p class="bio">${person.bio}</p>
 </div>
`;

document.body.innerHTML = markup;
```

Comment: A good answer should explain why the OP has their issue and how your code fixes it.

Comment: @mose Raguzzini after using your solution, I have found `<a classname="peoplelink" onclick="{this.demoButton}" id="moroni2">Moroni</a>` and please see that this is not pure html

Comment: Please share a snippet I assure it renders pure HTML

Comment: before converting(it is simple string)   `The record eventually reaches <a className="peoplelink" onClick={this.demoButton} id="moroni2">Moroni</a>, who again translates it and adds his synopsis to <a className="peoplelink" onClick={this.demoButton} id="mormon2">his father</a>’s record`            { **after converting**}      `The record eventually reaches <a classname="peoplelink" onclick="{this.demoButton}" id="moroni2">Moroni</a>, who again translates it and adds his synopsis to <a classname="peoplelink" onclick="{this.demoButton}" id="mormon2">his father</a>’s record ` this is browser html

Comment: Did you miss the string interpolation with backtick  (´´) ${variable}